# Regex Verification of String in Correct Order with Delimiters in PHP

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a expression to verify that the string supplied is a valid format, but it seems that if I don't use regex in a few months, I forget everything I learned and have to relearn it.

My expression is supposed to match a format like this: 010L0404FFCCAANFFCC00M000000XXXXXX
The four delimiters are (L, N, K, M) which arent in the 0-9A-F hexidecimal range to indicate uniqueness **must be in that order** or not in the list. Each delimiter can only exist once!

It breaks down to this:

- Starts off with a 3 digit numbers, which is simply ^([0-9]{3}) and is always required
- Second set begins with L, and must be 2 digits + 2 digits + 6 hexdecimal and is optional
- Third set begins with N and must be a 6 digit hexdecimal and is optional
- The fourth set K is simply any amount of numbers and is optional
- The fifth set is M and can be any 6 hexdecimals or XXXXXX to indicate nothing, it must be in multiples of 6 excluding 0, like 336699 (6) or 336699XXXXXXFFCC00 (18) and is optional

The hardest part I cant figure out making it require it in that order, and in multiples, like the L delimiter must come before and K always if it's there (the reason so I don't get variations of the same string which means the same thing with delimiters swapped). I can already parse it, I just want to verify the string is the correct format.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring the order isn't too bad.  Just make each set optional.  The regex will still match in order, so if the L section, for example, isn't there and the next character is N, it won't let L occur later since it won't match any of the rest of the regex.

I believe a direct translation of your requirements would be:

```
^([0-9]{3})(L[0-9]{4}[0-9A-F]{6})?(N[0-9A-F]{6})?(K[0-9]+)?(M([0-9A-F]{6}|X{6})+)?$
```

No real tricks, just making each group optional except for the first three digits, and adding an internal alternative for the two patterns of six digits in the M block.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, thanks for the help. For anyone reading, slight typo M([0-9A-Z] should be M([0-9A-F]

Answer (score 1):

```
^([0-9]{3})(L[0-9]{4}[0-9A-F]{6})?(N[0-9A-F]{6})?(K[0-9]+)?(M([0-9A-F]{6})+|MX{6})$
```

Comment: Whoops, overlooked your example 336699XXXXXXFFCC00. Oh well.

Comment: Is there a way to do specify to regex to do multiples of  6 for the M group?

Comment: Yes, the M group can be done exactly as @rra already has it: `(M([0-9A-F]{6}|X{6})+)?`